# Pandas groupby one column, agg another and select from a third

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns,

```
filename,area,fidx
1,123,0
1,45,1
1,6546,2
1,23,3
1,435,4
....
```

I want to select 4 frames `fidx` for each filename such that they are the `min`, `max`, `33 percentile` and `66 percentile` of the area. Each filename has about 100+ frames. The purpose of the selection is to have a spread so it doesn't necessary have to be the 33/66 percentile. The expected output would be

```
filename,area,fidx
1,123,0
1,6546,2
1,23,3
1,435,4
```

I know this is a groupby and agg the area but then I'm lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

1. sort the data by filename and area
2. once sorted, say, you have N data, then you want [0, N//3, (2*N)//3, N-1], which can be done by `iloc`

So:

```
def equal_sample(data):
    N = len(data)
    idx = [0, N//3, (2*N)//3, N-1]
    return data.iloc[idx]

(df.sort_values(['filename','area'])
   .groupby('filename')
   .apply(equal_sample)
)
```

**note** I just realized that this is equal location sampling, not quantile. You can do so by computing the quantile, then no.search_sorted or pd.merge_as_of. Will update the answer when have chance.

---

**Update** As commented above, it can go like this:

```
pct = pd.merge_asof(df.groupby('filename')['area']
                      .apply(lambda x: x.quantile(np.arange(4)/3))
                      .reset_index(),
                    df.assign(area=df['area'].astype(float)).sort_values('area'),
                    by='filename',
                    on='area'
                   )
```

Comment: Your first one worked great, the updated code is giving `*** ValueError: left keys must be sorted`, i tried sorting but still getting that error

Comment: `df.groupby(...).apply(...).reseet_index().sort_values('area')`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`np.percentile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) to find the appropriate `area` values for each `filename` and use that to create a mask for the dataframe:

```py
import numpy as np

def percentiles(g):
   p = np.percentile(g, [0, 33, 66, 100], method='nearest')
   return np.isin(g, p)

mask = df.groupby('filename')['area'].transform(percentiles)
df = df[mask].drop_duplicates(['filename', 'area'])
```

Output:

```
   filename  area  fidx
1         1    45     1
2         1  6546     2
3         1    23     3
4         1   435     4
```

Note that for your sample data the group is so small that `np.percentile` doesn't yield a great result. For a larger group it should yield better results.

Comment: the df is 2.8mil with 2014 unique filename so I expect at most 16112 (2014*4) rows but your code is giving me 1,027,362 rows, not sure what's wrong

Comment: @Kenan my bad, I didn't consider duplicate `area` values for a given `filename`. Please see my edit, that should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def custom_agg(series):
    return np.percentile(series, [0, 33, 66, 100])

result = df.groupby('filename')['area'].agg(custom_agg).reset_index()

selected_rows = pd.concat([
    df[(df['filename'] == row['filename']) & (df['area'] == row[0])]
    for _, row in result.iterrows()
])

print(selected_rows)
```

Comment: This code doesn't actually work; it gives a `ValueError: Must produce aggregated value`